# Which is the correct spelling: "Granddad" or "Grand-dad" or "Grandad"?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation, kinship-terms, doubled-consonants

*Granddad* or *Grand-dad* or *Grandad*?

Which is the correct spelling?

Comment: But don’t forget *Grampa* and *Gramps* or *Gramma*. All are common in the United States.

Comment: ... Grandfather

Comment: +1, I just stumbled upon the "grandad" spelling. It just doesn't feel right to me. But then again, I prefer the American spelling for most things.

Comment: The correct spelling is "TODOKETE"

Answer (score 16):

According to Google NGram, in [British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=granddad,grandad,grandpa,gramps&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,granddad;,c0;.t1;,grandad;,c0;.t1;,grandpa;,c0;.t1;,gramps;,c0) the spelling "grandad" is more popular than "granddad", however [American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=granddad,grandad,grandpa,gramps&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,granddad;,c0;.t1;,grandad;,c0;.t1;,grandpa;,c0;.t1;,gramps;,c0), the spelling "granddad" is more popular than "grandad".

American English:

[image]

British English:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Both exist, apparently.

The NOAD, says

> **granddad** |ˈgranˌdad| (also grandad) *noun informal* - one's grandfather.
>
> **grandad** |ˈgranˌdad|, *Noun* - variant spelling of granddad .

The [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/grandad) says the same thing, and is more specific, saying that "*Granddad*" is North-American English. `If someone from U.S./UK can confirm, it would add more info.`

Comment: I don't have a copy of OED to confirm, but anecdotally I can confirm as a native en-gb speaker that I find the spelling with a double d marked.

Comment: @Peter Taylor: Thanks for your comment! So your point is that you, as a UK English speaker, would say "Grandad"?

Comment: @Peter: I on the other hand (en-US) find the single-d spelling to be marked.

Comment: @Alenanno, yes, I write "grandad" and pronounce it gran-dad. (For completeness, I write "grandpa" and "grandma" but the d is barely there when I say them).

Comment: BE speaker - I would say single 'd'

Comment: Thanks to both. So it confirms what I found... "Grandpa" definitely solves the dilemma though ahah :)

Comment: And I (US, NE) write *granddad* and say [gɹændˑæːd]; *grandma* is [gɹæmːə]. Everybody's unique. :P

Comment: NE = New England?

Answer (score 6):

Further documentary evidence.

Clive Dunn's only #1 hit record, the famously ironic post punk single – **Grandad**, was spelled with one 'd'

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, we have a winner.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, I've generally seen 'Grandad' used, particularly among the older generations containing a preponderance of grandads. So I'd say that's the correct spelling in British English, and from the other answers 'Granddad' appears to be more common is US English.

Comment: [Chambers Dictionary](http://http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=grandad&title=21st) (which generally reflects BrE) gives both alternatives, with *grandad* first (which is how I've always spelt it).

Comment: The spelling appears illogical but similar things happen in other languages e.g. Grand-Rue and Grand-Place in French, when both words are feminine and would normally take the feminine form of the adjective.

Answer (score 0):

Searching Irish websites using Google:

- grandad 411,000
- grandpa 371,000
- granddad 41,600
- grand-dad/grand-dad 10,200
- grandaddy 7,230
- granddaddy 4,230